# Drawing line in d3js results in d3.v5.min.js:2 Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number

Tags: javascript, d3.js, linechart

I have a dual y-axes chart, in which I want to display bars for total score and a line for average score.
After playing around, I have everything configured, except the line which fails to show.

I get the console error `d3.v5.min.js:2 Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,189.02173913…".`
So I think there's something wrong with my `lineFunction`, but I don't see what, it should return x and y values to plot the line.
I used [this page](https://bl.ocks.org/gordlea/27370d1eea8464b04538e6d8ced39e89) as inspiration

I already checked for solutions to similar answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37252425/d3-js-d3-min-js1-error-path-attribute-d-expected-number-mnan-nanlnan-na/37535473) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49599840/d3-js-line-graph-error-path-attribute-d-expected-number), but my `Average` variable is already a number, so that seems to be ok in my case.

What am I missing?

My code:

```js
//// VERTICAL BAR CHART WITH SVG AND NAMES SINGLE X AND DUAL Y AXES
  // Create data array of values to visualize
  var dataArray = [{ "Player": "John Doe", "Points": 23, "Average": 4.5 }, { "Player": "Jane Doe", "Points": 13, "Average": 2.3 }, { "Player": "Mary Jane", "Points": 21, "Average": 1.5 }, { "Player": "Debasis Das", "Points": 14, "Average": 5.7 }, { "Player": "Nishant", "Points": 37, "Average": 5.9 }, { "Player": "Mark", "Points": 15, "Average": 6.2 }, { "Player": "Andrew", "Points": 18, "Average": 1.2 }, { "Player": "Simon", "Points": 34, "Average": 3.1 }, { "Player": "Lisa", "Points": 30, "Average": 9.2 }, { "Player": "Marga", "Points": 20, "Average": 7.8 }];

  // Create variable for the SVG
  var canvas = d3.select(".v5chart").append("g").attr("transform", "translate(20,30)");

  var canvasWidth = 500;


  var maxValue = d3.max(dataArray, function (d) { return d.Points; });
  var maxValue2 = d3.max(dataArray, function (d) { return d.Average; });
  //console.error("maxValue2:" + maxValue2);
  var canvasHeight = maxValue * 10;
  var canvasHeight2 = maxValue2 * 10;

  //make sure y-axes are equal in height
  if (canvasHeight > canvasHeight2) {canvasHeight2 = canvasHeight;}
  else if (canvasHeight < canvasHeight2) {canvasHeight = canvasHeight2;}

  var heightScale = d3.scaleLinear()
   .domain([0, d3.max(dataArray, function (d) { return d.Points; })])
   .range([canvasHeight, 0]); //use max value (37) * 10
  var y_axis = d3.axisLeft()
   .scale(heightScale);

  var heightScale2 = d3.scaleLinear()
   .domain([0, d3.max(dataArray, function (d) { return d.Average; })])
   .range([canvasHeight2, 0]); 
  var y_axis2 = d3.axisRight()
   .scale(heightScale2);



  //band settings x axis
  var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
   .domain(dataArray.map(function (d) { return d.Player; }))
   .range([0, canvasWidth]).padding([0.1]);
  var x_Axis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);

  // create bars
  canvas.selectAll("rect")
   .data(dataArray)
   .enter().append("rect")
   .attr("class", "bar")
   .attr("height", function (d, i) { return (d.Points * 10) })
   .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
   .attr("x", function (d, i) { return xScale(d.Player); })
   .attr("y", function (d, i) { return canvasHeight - (d.Points * 10) });

  // text for in vertical bars
  canvas.selectAll("text")
   .data(dataArray)
   .enter().append("text")
   .text(function (d) { return d.Points })
   .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
   .attr("class", "text")
   .attr("x", function (d, i) { return (xScale(d.Player) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2); })
   .attr("y", function (d, i) { return canvasHeight + 20 - (d.Points * 10) });




  var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
   .domain([0, maxValue2]) // input 
   .range([canvasHeight2, 0]); // output

  var lineFunction = d3.line()
   .x(function (d, i) { return xScale(i); }) // set the x values for the line generator
   .y(function (d, i) { return yScale(d.Average); }) // set the y values for the line generator 
   .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX); // apply smoothing to the line
  
  // 4. Call the y axis in a group tag
  canvas.append("g")
   .attr("class", "y axis")
   .call(d3.axisRight(yScale)) // Create an axis component with d3.axisLeft
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + canvasWidth + ",0)")
   .append("text")
   .attr("fill", "#000")
   .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
   .attr("y", 6)
   .attr("dy", "-1em")
   .attr("text-anchor", "end")
   .text("Average");


  canvas.append("path")
   .attr("class", "line")
   .attr("d", lineFunction(dataArray));

canvas.selectAll(".dot")
    .data(dataArray)
    .enter().append("circle") // Uses the enter().append() method
    .attr("class", "dot") // Assign a class for styling
    .attr("cx", function (d, i) { return xScale(d.Player) })
    .attr("cy", function (d) { return yScale(d.Average) })
    .attr("r", 5)
    .on("mouseover", function (a, b, c) {
        console.log(a)
        //this.attr('class', 'focus')
    })
    .on("mouseout", function () { })
    .append("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function (d) {
        return d.Average;
    });
  
  //y axis 1 settings
  canvas.append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
   .call(y_axis)
   .append("text")
   .attr("fill", "#000")
   .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
   .attr("y", 6)
   .attr("dy", "0.71em")
   .attr("text-anchor", "end")
   .text("Points");

  //x axis
  canvas.append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(0," + canvasHeight + ")")
   .call(x_Axis)
   .selectAll("text")
   .attr("x", 30)
   .attr("transform", function (d) {
    return "rotate(65)"
   });
```

```css
/*Rectangle bar class styling*/
 .bar {
   fill: #0080FF
 }
 .bar:hover {
   fill: #003366
 }

 /*Text class styling*/
 .text {
   fill: white;
   font-family: sans-serif
 }


 /* Style the lines by removing the fill and applying a stroke */
 .line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ffab00;
  stroke-width: 3;
 }
   
 .overlay {
   fill: none;
   pointer-events: all;
 }

 /* Style the dots by assigning a fill and stroke */
 .dot {
  fill: #ffab00;
  stroke: #fff;
 }
   
   .focus circle {
   fill: none;
   stroke: steelblue;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
 <svg class="v5chart" width="960" height="500"></svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In docs of d3;

> The first element in domain will be mapped to the first band, the
>   second domain value to the second band, and so on. Domain values are
>   stored internally in a map from stringified value to index; the
>   resulting index is then used to determine the band. Thus, a band
>   scale’s values must be coercible to a string, and the stringified
>   version of the domain value uniquely identifies the corresponding
>   band. If domain is not specified, this method returns the current
>   domain.

But in your xScale function, you are using mapped values of dataArray with Player key. I mean if you want to get any correct number from xScale function, you have to use it with Player key like 'John Doe', 'Jane Doe' etc.

In summary, if you change the line function to this one, you will see the result:

```
var lineFunction = d3.line()
        .x(function (d, i) { return xScale(d.Player); /*return xScale(i)*/ })
        .y(function (d, i) { return yScale(d.Average); })
        .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX);
```

I guess, you want to fix alignment problem after this. Its up to you.